# CSS - Strange border behaviour

Tags: css, firefox, border

I have a `div`, which has it's `border` property set to:

`border: 1px solid #3a87ad;`

When I inspect this div in my browser (using Firefox 60.0.1), the computed values for the border are 0.6 px. This wouldn't be an issue alone, but I am using multiple numbers of these divs in a plugin, which places them one below the other, and when it calculates the top position of each div, it uses exact values. After 3-4 divs placed, I can see a tiny white line (the extra white-space from the borders), that starts adding up on the screen.

Unfortunatly, I can't provide a fiddle, as the code is too large, but I am hoping someone else also experienced simmilar issues, and knows a solution.

What I already tried, is refreshing my zoom settings in the browser, but that didn't help either, viewing on 100% zoom, the problem still persists.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you looked into using `rems` or `ems` instead of pixels? I'm not sure if that would solve it... Is border-box being applied? [Link](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_box-sizing.asp).

Comment: `rems` or `ems` are out of the question, because of the plugin settings:( border-box is applied

Answer (score 0):

I think your code is overridden by some other CSS you use in your Plugin

Check it Carefully

and try `border: 1px solid #3a87ad!important;`

I hope it works